# LINQ to Xml Select Element

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I'm having some real issue's getting an element value from my XML. I've always seemed to have problems with XML. Code that works perfectly for others wont for mine, I must be missing something but i have no idea what.

I have the following XML:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<license xmlns="http://http://lilleker-it.co.uk/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <SID>S-1-5-21-1231312-12344234-12312312</SID>
   <Email>me@myurl.com</Email>
   <Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
      <SignedInfo>
         <CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315" />
         <SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1" />
         <Reference URI="">
            <Transforms>
               <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature" />
            </Transforms>
            <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1" />
            <DigestValue>aZd9Jsbqif+8KKRYuaKzuXTLPGA=</DigestValue>
         </Reference>
      </SignedInfo>
      <SignatureValue>PB613rI/Nh4E3LBY0pG52vTCsH6dple2nXXjnnHhpsW2ZOG6lcMPmPmQWAzZVEPDPACg44Tn37hBoRBoRZ4T98qwB5tRfDRD9jXgcC912334dfDFADdcdkoYXTSiVaVWsUe4x3T665VKf8Dej2e9bFXOuhCegXA5BP1Jeak=</SignatureValue>
   </Signature>
</license>
```

What i need is to select the value of Email and SID, however i just cannot seem to get it to work, i have tried the following code:

```
var query = doc.Descendants("license").Select(s => new
                {
                    EMAIL = s.Element("Email").Value,
                    SID = s.Element("SID").Value
                }).ToList();
                string e = query[0].EMAIL;
                string id = query[0].SID;
```

As well as:

```
string e = doc.Root.Element("license")
              .Elements("Email")
              .SingleOrDefault()
              .Value;
```

None of these returns a value, always null and i cannot see why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both of your sample code snippets will fail because they're looking for elements in no namespace. Your second sample will *also* fail because you're looking for a `license` element *under* the root element, when in fact it *is* the root element.

You need to use the right namespace. For example, to fix your first query (because that looks like it's doing more of what you want) you'd use:

```
XNamespace ns = "http://http://lilleker-it.co.uk/";
var query = doc.Descendants(ns + "license").Select(s => new
                {
                    EMAIL = s.Element(ns + "Email").Value,
                    SID = s.Element(ns + "SID").Value
                }).ToList();
string e = query[0].EMAIL;
string id = query[0].SID;
```

Although personally I'd handle it rather differently:

```
XNamespace ns = "http://http://lilleker-it.co.uk/";
string e = (string) doc.Root.Element(ns + "Email");
string id = (string) doc.Root.Element(ns + "SID");
```

There's no need to use a LINQ query at all here - just find the first element under the root with the right name, and convert it to a string. That will give you a `null` value for each of `s` or `id` if the corresponding element is missing, so you can detect that easily and handle it appropriately.

Comment: Thank you, that works perfectly. I guess my understanding of xml is still a little off. Unfortunately i cannot accept your answer yet because of this silly timer. However i will come back and accept.